# Avro Schema is being generated in wrong field order (alphabetical)

Tags: java, reflection, avro

I have a class the I need to converto to an avro schema:

```
public class MonitorStateSchema {
    private MetaResponse c;
    private Header a;
    private MonitorStateEnvelope b;

    public MonitorStateSchema(MetaResponse c, Header a, MonitorStateEnvelope b) {
        this.c = c;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

I use a generic method to get the schema from it

```
public static <D> void getFromAvro(Class<D> schemaType) {
    Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(schemaType);

   // other stuff
}
```

After doing it, I got a different order in the result than the expected:

EXPECTED:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MonitorSchema",
  "namespace": "mypackage.monitor",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "c",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "MetaResponse",
        "namespace": "mypackage.monitor",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "uuid",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "code",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "message",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "a",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Header",
        "namespace": "mypackage.monitor",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "apiKey",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "signature",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "nonce",
            "type": "int"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "MonitorEnvelope",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "fields",
            "type": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Field",
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "value",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "java-class": "[Lmypackage.monitor.Field;"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

ACTUAL RESULT:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MonitorStateSchema",
  "namespace": "mypackage.monitor",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "a",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Header",
        "namespace": "mypackage.monitor",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "apiKey",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "nonce",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "signature",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "MonitorStateEnvelope",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "fields",
            "type": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Field",
                "namespace": "mypackage.monitor",
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "value",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "java-class": "[Lmypackage.monitor.Field;"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "c",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "MetaResponse",
        "namespace": "mypackage.monitor",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "code",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "message",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "uuid",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Seems that it is ordering by alphabetical order on the name of the field and it is breaking the application when deserializing the byte array. Is there any reason for this to happen?

Comment: Have you tried getRecordSchema(Object o) instead of getSchema(Type t)? This alphabetical ordering seems very strange though.

Comment: Fields do not have an ordering. `Class.getFields()` may return fields in any arbitrary order.

Comment: Avro version 1.10.0 changed ReflectData to [sort fields into alphabetical order](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2579). Some people [complained that was a breaking change](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-3138).

Comment: @ChinHuang does it still have this behavior on 1.11.0? If so, how can I properly convert N array of bytes to this schema in an order that was not expected?

Comment: @Csisanyi It is not the case. I have an array of bytes and need to convert to an Object. I do not have the Object o, just the schema of the Object.class

Comment: @ChinHuang, the version was the issue. Would you mind writting the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avro version 1.10.0 changed ReflectData to [sort fields into alphabetical order](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2579) because the Class.getDeclaredFields() method API specification does not mandate a specific order of the fields that get returned. Some Java implementations return the fields in the order they appear in the Java source file. Some people [complained that was a breaking change](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-3138).

If you don't want the fields sorted into alphabetical order, then you must stay at Avro version 1.9.2 or lower.